# count uniq ids between column and index (like pivot table)

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, pivot-table

I have a table:

| id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 2 | C |
| 3 | B |
| 3 | C |
| 4 | C |
| 4 | A |

And I need a new table where unique IDs are calculated at the intersection of names. That is, for example, ID 2 has both A and B, that is, at the intersection of A and B, there is already one ID. Something like this:

| Name | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | - | 1 | 2 |
| B | 1 | - | 2 |
| C | 2 | 2 | - |

I tried with pandas.pivot_table, but i couldn't understand how

Comment: I think `A-C` and `C-A` should be `2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us use `crosstab` to create frequency table, then calculate the inner product to generate similarity / intersection matrix and mask the diagonal values with `0`

```
s = pd.crosstab(df['Name'], df['id']).clip(upper=1)
s = s @ s.T
np.fill_diagonal(s.values, 0)
```

---

```
print(s)

Name  A  B  C
Name         
A     0  1  2
B     1  0  2
C     2  2  0
```